# Jenkins Error: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException

Tags: jenkins

I have installed successfully Jenkins after the next day, I have tried to reopen by restarting the Service:Jenkins and got this error.

Should I reinstall Jenkins ?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: looks like something is wrong in your config.xml

Comment: I have checked this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\config and has no data when opened in notepad

Comment: By any chance, did you forget the suffix `.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the lockout follow these steps to manually change the version, which could just be back to your old working version.

- Stop the Jenkins windows service
- Rename war directory to war.bak
- Rename jenkins.war to jenkins.war.bak
- Get a new war file from `https://updates.jenkins.io/download/war/`
- Copy new jenkins.war into jenkins directory
- Start Jenkins windows service
- Observe creation of war directory which will now contain contents of jenkins.war archive
- Navigate to jenkins home page, at which point you will be informed
  that Jenkins is preparing your installation
- Once complete, test your
  existing jobs to verify compatability
- Navigate to 'Manage Jenkins'
  via the menu and Action any notifications displayed - plugins, data
  format conversions etc.
- Delete jenkins.war.bak file and war.bak folder

  After following those steps you will be able to get back into Jenkins, you might have other version issues with plug-ins but at least you can get back in and not lose everything.  Also always put your pipeline scripts in source control and use a back up plug in for Jenkins.